# Is ROS a registred trademark?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this page the acronym "ROS" is used as "Restaurant operating system"

http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/miso-robotics-unveils-flippy-in-caliburger-kitchen-plans-worldwide-rollout-300419426.html

Is it legal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256682/is-ros-a-registred-trademark?/) by [Fabio](https://answers.ros.org/users/22620/fabio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Tradmark information can be found at: https://www.ros.org/blog/media/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0